# How does International travel work in HP universe?

Tags: harry-potter

Do magical folk need to travel by plane or ship to cross the Atlantic? I have a feeling if not already answered, this question will be answered in the upcoming movie.

Obviously there are means of instant travel but would they work for such a long journey? Is the Floo Network international? Can you Apparate over any distance? Portkeys?

If these methods are used, how are they regulated? There are many rules regarding Customs & Immigration in the Muggle world. If the Ministry of Magic has similar rules, how are they enforced with instant direct travel as mentioned above?

Comment: If I remember right, you can't apparate over long distances, hence Voldemort's flying.

Comment: Related: [What is the fastest way to travel in the Harry Potter universe?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/67694/what-is-fastest-way-to-travel-in-harry-potter-universe)

Comment: New Fantastic Beasts trailer show our hero Newt on a ship... not sure if this is standard or NOTM (Newt Only Transportation Method)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**There are a few examples of international travel.**

During the Triwizard Tournament:

- The Beauxbatons arrived in a large carriage pulled by Abraxan horses.
- The Durmstrang arrived via a large ship which could travel underwater.

In those two cases, they were bringing students who likely hadn't all learned to Apparate yet.

When the Weasleys were going on vacation to Egypt, there is no mention of how they all went. I think the assumption is either Portkey or perhaps an international Floo Network, given the complete lack of competence the Weasleys demonstrate towards Muggle methods.

Later Voldemort traveled to and from Nurmengard  (Germany or Bulgaria) back to England. He flies until he is close enough to his destination to Apparate.

Since you could in theory fly anywhere, as long as you were patient enough, you could use a flying car or motorcycle, a broomstick, or any creature which can fly and support a human (Thestral, Dragon, Hippogriff).

**Update:**

In *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them*, Newt both arrives and leaves from New York via a traditional steam ship. Now, it isn't clear whether that was by necessity or not. He kind of sneaks into America with a suitcase full of illegal beasts. Perhaps if he had gone via Floo Network / Portkey, he would have had to go through magic customs or something.

Additionally, On Pottermore, under *Ilvermorny School of Witchcraft and Wizardry*, Isolt Sayre traveled from Ireland to America via the Mayflower. She was also traveling incognito, and likely didn't have the normal magical contacts that would enable her to travel via magical methods. The two boys she rescues  (who had magical parents) also traveled by boat and had settled in Plymouth. Presumably this means they were on the Mayflower together, and didn't know it. Gormlaith also travels by boat to America in order to seek her revenge against Isolt.

**I've written this song to commemorate travel in the Harry Potter world:**

> All right stop, Apparate and *listen*
>   Voldemort's back with a brand new invention
>   Flying! grab a hold of me tightly
>   Floo Network's dope like a Train leaving nightly
>   Will Thestrals stop? Yo, I don't know
>   Kill the lights and I'll Lumos Maximo
>   To the extreme I rock a Wand like a vandal
>   Find a Portkey and grab a Broom by the handle
>
> Fly!
>   Atop a big Hippogriff
>   Find a horcrux near a seaside cliff
>   Deadly, like Avada Kedevra
>   Azkaban Prison is another matter
>   Snitch it or Quidditch
>   You better set Sail
>   You better not hex or you'll be Dragon tail
>   If there was a goblin
>   Yo, I'll be slick
>   Transfigure a teapot with a simple wrist flick
>
> Harry Harry Potter

Comment: He flies until he's close enough to Apparate.

Comment: Yeah, but that's what it says in the book, i'm pretty sure.

Comment: But Voldemort is one of maybe a handful of wizard who can fly. Also, I have to imagine any flying by broom or an individual is slow.

Comment: Also, those two methods are the school transports. Is there any suggestion that there are numerous types of flying carriages and underwater ships available to the general population?

Comment: @Skooba Well the Weasleys built a flying car, and Sirius built a flying motorcycle. It seems making other vehicles fly isn't a big deal.

Comment: Good points Jack. Even though those vehicles were made illegally, the magic is there.

Comment: @JackBNimble I was about to upvote this, before I read the song part...

Comment: @randal'thor You are dead to me.

Comment: @randal'thor the song makes me WANT to upvote it!

Comment: Wondering what the last word on line six is for. I assumed the OP wasn't looking for a movie answer.

Comment: @ibid I needed something that rhymed with 'know'

Comment: @JackBNimble - It still makes this a movie answer.

Comment: @ibid, the OP specifically says his question might be answered by the upcoming movie. So why wouldn't he accept a movie answer?

Comment: @JackBNimble - There is a distinction between the FB movie (which is based on a script written by Rowling) and a part of a previous movie which directly contradicts the books.

Comment: Really? Ice Ice Baby? Which in itself was sued successfully for ripping off the bass riff?

Comment: @JohnP This is a completely original work.

Comment: I think that the transports in GoF were more about Making an Entrance that practicality.

Comment: @JackBNimble - I believe, that it could be successfully sued, as it immediately evokes the original. :p I will leave that to Vanilla, if he can be pried from his home redecorating business long enough.

Comment: +1 Just for the song.  @JohnP I believe this would be protected under fair use as parody, the same way Weird Al Yankovic gets away with all of his stuff.

Comment: @Forral - Yes, I know. I'm just twigging Jack :)

Answer (score 22):

### Portkeys - yes.

The answers to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/104395/31394) show that **Portkey travel can be international**. Copying quotes from my and DVK's answers over there:

- from **various places** to **the Sahara desert**:

  > "While there have been no proven referee slayings since [1357], there have been several incidences of broom-tampering over the centuries, the most dangerous being the transformation of the referee's broom into a Portkey, so that he or she is whisked away from the match halfway through and turns up months later in the Sahara Desert."
  >
  > <sub>-- Kennilworthy Whisp, *Quidditch Through the Ages*</sub>
- from **France** to **the Burrow**:

  > Mr. Weasley had therefore gone to meet the Delacours on top of a nearby hill, where they were to arrive by Portkey
  >
  > <sub>-- *HP and the Deathly Hallows*, Chapter 6: *The Ghoul In Pyjamas*</sub>
- from **Godric's Hollow** to **eastern Europe**:

  > “It was poor little Ariana dying, I think, that did it,” says Bathilda. “It came as an awful shock. Gellert was there in the house when it happened, and he came back to my house all of a dither, told me he wanted to go home the next day. Terribly distressed, you know. So I arranged a Portkey and that was the last I saw of him
  >
  > <sub>*HP and the Deathly Hallows*, Chapter 19, *The Life and Lies of Albus Dumbledore*</sub>

### Apparition - usually no.

The answers to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/10236/31394) show that there is some confusion and contradiction over whether or not Apparition can be international. Firstly, as stated in KeithS's answer, this quote from the books tells us that **there is a limit on the distance even a skilled wizard can Apparate**:

> Harry knew it; his scar was bursting with the pain of it, and he could feel Voldemort flying through the sky from far away, over a dark and stormy sea, and soon he would be close enough to Apparate to them, and Harry could see no way out.
>
> <sub>-- *HP and the Deathly Hallows*, Chapter 23: *Malfoy Manor*</sub>

The following quote from Kevin's answer tells us that it is **possible but risky to Apparate across continents**:

> Apparition becomes increasingly unreliable over very long distances, and only highly skilled wizards are wise to attempt it across continents.
>
> <sub>-- *Quidditch Through the Ages*, Chapter 9</sub>

And finally, Richard's answer tells us that **Apparition between countries is banned**.

### Floo - unclear.

All the information we have in canon concerns the Floo Network within Britain. This includes the [latest](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/the-floo-network) [articles](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/floo-powder) from Pottermore by JK Rowling. Quoting from the second of these sources:

> Floo powder was invented by Ignatia Wildsmith in the thirteenth century. Its manufacture is strictly controlled. The only licensed producer in Britain is Floo-Pow, a company whose Headquarters is in Diagon Alley, and who never answer their front door.

The inclusion of the words "in Britain" would seem to suggest that there *are* Floo Networks in other countries too, but doesn't tell us whether they're connected.

Comment: Great answer! And as you mentioned Appraition is banned. Should the Customs/Immigration question be separate?

Comment: The Floo network probably has a few international connections as well.  No reason it *couldn't.*

Answer (score 2):

I am at work so I will look up citations later on.

In HP GoF during the World Cup many international wizards Apparated - even though for larger groups the Ministry arranged the transport means. Also for the Triwizard tournament we saw that there are alternative means for groups to travel, as the guests arrived in a magical boat and a carriage.

Also in GoF, they were discussing that ministry worker, Bertha Jorkins, who disappeared, saying that she probably Apparated on a wrong location (by Mr. Bagman to Mr. Weasley) and ended up in Australia instead of Albania - so we know it is possible to do it over long distances.

In HBP Hagrid and his lady friend, Madame Maxime, used Muggle transport to get to France and made sure they were followed.